ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'minio' when submitting a PySpark job on Google Cloud Dataproc
I’m facing an issue when trying to submit a PySpark job to Google Cloud Dataproc. The goal is to run a script on the Dataproc cluster that uses the minio module. However, I keep encountering the following error:
enter image description here
This is my code that i submit in dataproc:
enter image description here
My Dataproc cluster consists of 1 master node and 2 worker nodes.

I'm submitting the job using the gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark command.
I packaged my environment, including the minio module, into a .tar.gz file and uploaded it to Google Cloud Storage. I referenced it using the --py-files flag.
I also tried using a requirements.txt file that specifies minio as a dependency.

How can I correctly install and use the minio module in a PySpark job on Google Cloud Dataproc?

You shouldn't be posting images. Code is made of text. Use a [code block] instead.

Please share more information about your cluster and your submit command (is it serverless or more standard cluster ext.?). The potential reasons that come to my mind from what you've shared so far are:

While preparing the tar.gz file, the minio path may not be accessible. For this, maybe you can try to make minio a separate package and use it with the flag you shared. I would also like to remind, as I remember --py-files flag will not work in serverless data proc clusters.
Apart from this, you can check whether the service account you use in the dataproc cluster has access to the bucket where the minio file is located (high probability there is already, but you can double check).
Finally, you can try using Initialization actions as an alternative way, please check this:

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions
How to install python packages in a Google Dataproc cluster



I hope your problem will be solved!
